# Primefaces colorpicker is not displayed

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Here is my xmlns':

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
      xmlns:pf="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Here is my form:

```
<h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:inputText styleClass="input textarea" p:placeholder="topic" value="#{postBean.topic}" />
                <pf:colorPicker id="inlineCP" value="#{postBean.color}" mode="inline" />
                <h:inputTextarea styleClass="textarea" value="#{postBean.message}" p:placeholder="enter your note here..." rows="4" />

                <h:commandButton styleClass="reload btn save_post_btn" action="#{postBean.savePost()}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

After that colorpicker is not displayed. why?

Comment: I see the problem. <pf:colorpicker> should be located between <pf:panel> tags. After that it is displayed but popup does not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, Sujan. I did. First of all I removed jQerry tag from page's head (<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>). This was the reason of popup blocking.

Comment: My answer is off-topic, because I didn't understand which pop-up you were talking about. Next time please post full code, and explain clearly what you want in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pf:colorpicker` is inline mode. Remove the inline part along with the `mode` attribute if you want a pop-up.

By default the mode is pop-up.